# Trying to integrate $\pi\int_0^h ((-r/h)x+r)^2 \,dx$

Tags: integration

> I am trying to solve this integral:  $\pi\int_0^h ((-r/h)x+r)^2 \,dx$.

This is what i have done:
$u=(-r/h)x+r$
$dx=(-h/r) du$

$$\pi\int_0^h ((-r/h)x+r)^2 \,dx =\pi\int_0^h u^2(-h/r)\,du=\pi(-h/r)\int_0^h u^2du=\pi\left(-\frac{h}{r}\right)\frac {u^3}{3}=\pi(-h/r)\frac {((-r/h)x+r)^3}{3}$$

The problem I have is when I substitute $x$ by zero and $h$ and the result is $-\pi h r^2 / 3$.

The result its supposed to be $\pi h r^2 / 3$.

I would be very grateful if you could help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\pi\int_{0}^{h}\left(\left(-\frac rh\right)x+r\right)^2dx=\pi\int_{\color{red}r}^{\color{red}0}u^2\left(-\frac hr\right)du$$

Comment: Im an idiot :-)..  
I just realized that $\int_0^h f(x)dx = F(h) - F(0) $  
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

$$\pi\int_{0}^{h}\left(\left(-\frac{r}{h}\right)x+r\right)^2\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\pi\int_{0}^{h}\left(r-\frac{rx}{h}\right)^2\space\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=r-\frac{rx}{h}$ and $\text{d}u=-\frac{r}{h}\space\space\text{d}x$. This gives a new lower bound $u=r-\frac{0\cdot r}{h}=r$ and new upper bound $u=r-\frac{hr}{h}=0$:

---

$$-\frac{\pi h}{r}\int_{r}^{0}u^2\space\space\text{d}u=$$
$$-\frac{\pi h}{r}\left[\frac{u^3}{3}\right]_{r}^{0}=$$
$$-\frac{\pi h}{3r}\left[u^3\right]_{r}^{0}=$$
$$-\frac{\pi h}{3r}\left(0^3-r^3\right)=$$
$$-\frac{\pi h}{3r}\left(0-r^3\right)=$$
$$-\frac{\pi h}{3r}\left(-r^3\right)=$$
$$\frac{\pi hr^3}{3r}=$$
$$\frac{\pi hr^2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}\pi h r^2$$